# How to use HelperForm from the FrontController in PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: php, helper, prestashop-1.6

I was trying to do a form with the helperForm, but it was imposible.
I was following the official documentation, but was imposible for me from the FrontControler.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperForm+class

Can i do that??

The error that show to me is:

```
Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file 'helpers/form/form.tpl'
```

And my class is:

```
public function renderForm()
  { 
    $fields_form = array( 'form' => array(
      'legend' => array(       
        'title' => $this->module->l('Edit carrier'),       
        'image' => '../img/admin/icon_to_display.gif'   
      ),   
      'input' => array(       
        array(           
          'type' => 'text',
          'name' => 'shipping_method',
         ),
      ),
      'submit' => array(
        'title' => $this->module->l('Save'),       
        'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'   
      )
    ));

    $helper = new HelperForm();
    $helper->show_toolbar = false;
    $helper->table = $this->table;
    $this->fields_form = array();

    $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
    $helper->submit_action = 'submitBlockCart';

    return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
}
```

I'm going crazy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: You CAN NOT use HelperForm from the FrontEnd.

As far as I know you can use the helperForm only in the BackOffice, so I don't think you can in the front.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't know if you *should*, but you certainly *can* use the `HelperForm` in a custom module.

Have a look at the function `createTemplate` from the `Helper` class (which `HelperForm` extends) in `/classes/helper/Helper.php` and in particular at this piece of code:

```
elseif ($this->module) {
    $override_tpl_path = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/_configure/'.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name;
}
```

You can see that if you define the property `module`, the helper will use the template `form.tpl` inside your module's folder, under `/views/templates/admin/_configure/helpers/form/`.

So what you need to do is:

1. Copy `form.tpl` from `admin/themes/default/template/helpers/form/form.tpl` to the above-mentioned path in your module
2. Place `$helper->module = $this;` before calling `generateForm()`

Note: 
In addition, you might also want to define `$helper->tpl_vars` to be able to use the property `name` of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I've already seen this kind of error on many thread. Is your `admin/themes/your_theme/template/helpers/form/form.tpl` present on your server and with the right access permissions?

Sometimes the whole `helpers` directory is missing for strange reasons.

---

**EDIT** Helper Form is only available for Back Office. You can't use it from a FrontController context.

Comment: Yep, it's true, but I download many Free themes and in all of them it is the same. Do you have that folder?? Could you pass me?

Comment: you can get it from [Prestashop website](https://www.prestashop.com/en/developers-versions#previous-version). Download the same version you use and copy the missing directory from the archive to your website.

Comment: I did that already, but I couldn't find it in the "default-bootstrap" theme. Do you have any clue?

Comment: You're trying to use it on front office?

Comment: Well, I am trying to use it on the Front End. I am doing a module to let de costumer upload a photo. Thats why I am useing the FrontControler. Can we do that??

Comment: No, I've updated my answer with this information. Helper Form is only available for the backoffice. You can't natively use it on the Front Office.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, the helpers are only for the BackEnd. Cheers

Comment: If this answers your question, could you please accept my answer to mark to thread as solved? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)